# Bootstrap 5 Tabs with Next/Prev Button

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5

How can I add prev/next buttons to bootstrap 5 tabs?

I've tried to use recommended methods for previous versions but the structure must be different. What am I missing here with the jQuery?

```js
$('.btnNext').click(function() {
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
$('.btnPrevious').click(function() {
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').prev('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane container active" id="home">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>

  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu1">
    <h1>Menu 1</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Back</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu2">
    <h1>Menu 2</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Back</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that the `active` class actually ends up on the *anchor* element after Bootstrap does its thing, so your child selector wasn't finding it.

Here I'm using [Bootstrap's `show` method](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navs-tabs/#show) rather than a click trigger. It's a bit more inline with Bootstrap's design pattern.

```js
$('.btnNext').click(function() {
  const nextTabLinkEl = $('.nav-tabs .active').closest('li').next('li').find('a')[0];
  const nextTab = new bootstrap.Tab(nextTabLinkEl);
  nextTab.show();
});

$('.btnPrevious').click(function() {
  const prevTabLinkEl = $('.nav-tabs .active').closest('li').prev('li').find('a')[0];
  const prevTab = new bootstrap.Tab(prevTabLinkEl);
  prevTab.show();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane container active" id="home">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>

  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu1">
    <h1>Menu 1</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Back</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu2">
    <h1>Menu 2</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Back</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```