# Bootstrap 5 Tabs with Next/Prev Button without jQuery

Tags: javascript, tabs, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to add Prev and Next buttons to bootstrap 5 tabs without using jQuery.

I have see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71341483/bootstrap-5-tabs-with-next-prev-button) with a perfect response, that I report below, but I'm not able to do the same thing in Javascript without jQuery.

Can anyone help me?

```js
$('.btnNext').click(function() {
  const nextTabLinkEl = $('.nav-tabs .active').closest('li').next('li').find('a')[0];
  const nextTab = new bootstrap.Tab(nextTabLinkEl);
  nextTab.show();
});

$('.btnPrevious').click(function() {
  const prevTabLinkEl = $('.nav-tabs .active').closest('li').prev('li').find('a')[0];
  const prevTab = new bootstrap.Tab(prevTabLinkEl);
  prevTab.show();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane container active" id="home">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>

  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu1">
    <h1>Menu 1</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Back</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu2">
    <h1>Menu 2</h1>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Back</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, this can easily be done with just a few lines of JavaScript and no jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You're still calling jQuery methods. You need to translate that logic into JavaScript if you want to avoid using jQuery. Your syntax and logic may end up looking different.

Refer to https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp as a starting point.

Remember to remove your jQuery script tag at the bottom of your HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example using only Javascript, there are several ways to do this, this is one of them, I hope it helps.

```js
const nextBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".btnNext");
const prevBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".btnPrev");

nextBtn.forEach(function(item, index){
    item.addEventListener('click', function(){
      let id = index + 1;
      let tabElement = document.querySelectorAll("#myTab li a")[id];
      var lastTab = new bootstrap.Tab(tabElement);
      lastTab.show();   
    });
});

prevBtn.forEach(function(item, index){
    item.addEventListener('click', function(){
      let id = index;
      let tabElement = document.querySelectorAll("#myTab li a")[id];
      var lastTab = new bootstrap.Tab(tabElement);
      lastTab.show();
    });
});
```

```html
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#home">Menu-1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu-2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu-3</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane container active" id="home">
    <h1>Menu-1</h1>
    TEXT A:......
    <hr>
    
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu1">
    <h1>Menu-2</h1>
    TEXT B:....
    <hr>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrev">Back</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu2">
    <h1>Menu-3</h1>
    TEXT C:....
    <hr>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btnPrev">Back</a>
    <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Comment: Please add supporting info to your answer to improve it.